# When a stochastic volatility model is calibrated?

Tags: stochastic-volatility

In an Investment Bank, how often a stochastic volatility model is calibrated ? Is it calibrated daily ? Is it calibrated whenever a pricing is required ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This depends largely on the model as well as the market, so there is no one-size-fits-all approach. Let us take the *Stochastic Alpha Beta Rho (SABR)* model, which has four parameters, as an example:

- $\alpha$, the initial instantaneous volatility of an ATM option. This is calibrated frequently and often intra-day due to the importance of ATM options.
- $\beta$, which describes the *backbone of volatility*. This is often chosen a priori and not calibrated.
- $\rho$, which describes the correlation betweent the Brownian motions driving the forward process and its vol proces, respectivelty. This is not calibrated as frequently - perhaps once a week/month depending on the market.
- $\nu$, which is the *vol of vol*. This is not calibrated as frequently - perhaps once a week/month depending of the market.

Have a look at the [initial paper by Pat Hagan et al.](https://www.next-finance.net/IMG/pdf/pdf_SABR.pdf) for more information!